# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value'): Todo List

Tags: javascript

I get back value undefined. I tried to change the code around and make sure the code is working propertly, but can't figure it out.

```
//Const, lets, and var

const form = document.getElementById('todoForm');
const todoInput = document.getElementById('todoInput')
//List

let todos = []
//Values


form.addEventListener('submit', event => {
    event.preventDefault()

    saveTodo();
})
//Save todo

function saveTodo() {
    const todoValues = todoInput.add.value;

    let values = {
        value: todoValues,
        checked: false,
        color: '#' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16)
    }

    todos.push(values)
}

console.log(todos)
```

Comment: What do you expect `todoInput.add` to be?

Comment: That is to record the value of a string of text.

Comment: Can you provide a [mre] with your HTML?

Comment: <body>
    <h1 class="title">ToDo List</h1>
    <form action="#" class="todoForm" id="todoForm">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Text" id="todoInput" />
      <button id="btn-form" class="btn-form">Enter</button>
    </form>

Comment: Fix it just need to change .add.value to .value; I thought it would add the value, but it didn't.